# Download zip file using angular js via Spring-based RESTful web service

Tags: angularjs, spring, java

I am very new to Angular Js, I need write code to download one zip file via Spring-based RESTful web service with 'download' button click. Web service is ready but don't know how to handle that API in angular js.

Comment: use `$http` to give API calls 
you can use this tutorial
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

use `$http` to give API calls.
You can use this tutorial
[Angular API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)